# In Debug at vs 2010 I see only values such as: 0x000000000625ef88 instead of human readable values

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

this is not related to Show hexadecimal.
I am using visual studio 2010, with win 7.
Any suggestions?

Comment: And what kind of value where you looking at?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Watch" window in Visual Studio (Debug -> Windows -> Watch), right-click, and uncheck the option "Hexadecimal Display"

Comment: I allready did that, this is the problem, no matter what I do I get this value, it is just a plain old object nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the visual studio settings by running the following command from :

Devenv /ResetSettings